# Can't get attributed string to work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to set some attributes of a string in code, but can't get `NSAttributedString` to work. This is the function, that's supposed to change the string:

```
func getAttributedString(string: String) -> NSAttributedString
{
    var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
    var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18.0)]

    attrString.setAttributes(attrs, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

    return attrString
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
if (self.product.packageDimensions != nil) {
        self.descriptionLabel.text = 
                   self.descriptionLabel.text + self.getAttributedString("Package dimensions:").string + 
                   "\n\(self.product.packageDimensions) \n"
    }
```

But the font stays the same. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think the concatenation of the attributed string with the non attributed string is causing the loss of formatting.

Comment: Unfortunately, even without the concatenation, the string doesn't get formatted

Comment: I don't use Swift, but shouldn't it be `self.descriptionLabel.attributedText =` instead?

Comment: It doesn't work with `self.descriptionLabel.attributedText` either.

Answer (score 3):

You make 2 errors in your code.

1. `setAttributes` needs a *Dictionary*, not an *Array*
2. when you use the `string` attribute, you will only get a `String`, all attributes are lost.

---

To add or change attributes to a attributedString it has to be **mutable**. You only get a `NSMutableString` from the `attributedText` attribute. If you want to change it create a mutable version from it and change it. Then you may set the attributedText to the new mutable version.

---

If you can give the attributed string as an argument, I will give you an example that works:

```
func setFontFor(attrString: NSAttributedString) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    var mutableAttrString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrString)
    let headerStart: Int = 0
    let headerEnd: Int = 13
    mutableAttrString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18.0), range: NSMakeRange(headerStart, headerEnd))

    return mutableAttrString
}
```

#### Usage:

```
myLabel.attributedText = setFontFor(myLabel.attributedText)
```

As you can see I used the `attributedText` property of the `UILabel` class, it also works for `UITextView` and others. If you have another label, you can create a new NSAttributedString with the initializer `NSAttributedString(normalString)` as you already used in the question code.

Comment: I want to format just a part of the text, so with this code I'd have to set the header text (which I want formatted) first, use the function and then append the rest, or am I getting it wrong ?

Comment: You are getting it wrong with NSAttributedString. You define the part you want to format with the range parameter. When you set the NSRange to the range of the text for your header, only that text will have the new attribute.

Comment: Changed it to more reflect your question in the comment

Comment: Well, this is the desired outcome: I want to style the header only, so I pass only it as the function parameter. But anyway, even with your code, it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried something easier to make sure it is not the fault of the function, like:         `label. attributedText = label.attributedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, label.attributedText.length))`?

Comment: Arg. Now I see for your case it might be a bit overkill to use the inout keyword, because the given **attributedText is not mutable**. But I tried/changed the code now and it works.

Comment: So for this case I changed the function to work without inout.

Comment: Ok, I tried `self.descriptionLabel.attributedText =NSAttributedString(string:"Description") 
self.descriptionLabel.attributedText = setFontFor(self.descriptionLabel.attributedText)` and I get a "value nil" error. I tried `self.descriptionLabel.attributedText = setFontFor(NSAttributedString(string:"Description"))` and the string still doesn't get formatted. So I think I'll just figure out a way to style it in IB and not from code.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (self.product.packageDimensions != nil) {
        self.descriptionLabel.attributedText = 
                   self.descriptionLabel.attributedText + self.getAttributedString("Package dimensions:").string + 
                   "\n\(self.product.packageDimensions) \n"
    }
```

You should use the `attributedText` [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText)