# Making text bold using attributed string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a string like this

```
var str = "@text1 this is good @text1"
```

Now replace `text1` with another string, say `t 1`. I am able to replace the text, but i am not able to bold it. I want to bold the new string `t 1`, so that the final output will be:

**@t 1** this is good **@t 1**

*How can I do it?*

All the examples I am seeing are in Objective-C, but I want to do it in Swift.

Comment: You need to decompose you issue: Learn how to "bold": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199580/cant-get-attributed-string-to-work-in-swift Learn how to replace text.

Comment: Use this library, it's petty simple.

https://github.com/iOSTechHub/AttributedString

Comment: `titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11)`

working perfect

Answer (score 309):

**Usage:**

```
let label = UILabel()
label.attributedText =
    NSMutableAttributedString()
        .bold("Address: ")
        .normal(" Kathmandu, Nepal\n\n")
        .orangeHighlight(" Email: ")
        .blackHighlight(" prajeet.shrestha@gmail.com ")
        .bold("\n\nCopyright: ")
        .underlined(" All rights reserved. 2020.")
```

**Result:**

[image]

Here is a neat way to make a combination of bold and normal texts in a single label plus some other bonus methods.

**Extension: Swift 5.***

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    var fontSize:CGFloat { return 14 }
    var boldFont:UIFont { return UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: fontSize) ?? UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize) }
    var normalFont:UIFont { return UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: fontSize) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)}
    
    func bold(_ value:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        
        let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .font : boldFont
        ]
        
        self.append(NSAttributedString(string: value, attributes:attributes))
        return self
    }
    
    func normal(_ value:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        
        let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .font : normalFont,
        ]
        
        self.append(NSAttributedString(string: value, attributes:attributes))
        return self
    }
    /* Other styling methods */
    func orangeHighlight(_ value:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        
        let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .font :  normalFont,
            .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
            .backgroundColor : UIColor.orange
        ]
        
        self.append(NSAttributedString(string: value, attributes:attributes))
        return self
    }
    
    func blackHighlight(_ value:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        
        let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .font :  normalFont,
            .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
            .backgroundColor : UIColor.black
            
        ]
        
        self.append(NSAttributedString(string: value, attributes:attributes))
        return self
    }
    
    func underlined(_ value:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        
        let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .font :  normalFont,
            .underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
            
        ]
        
        self.append(NSAttributedString(string: value, attributes:attributes))
        return self
    }
}
```

**Note:** If compiler is missing UIFont/UIColor, replace them with NSFont/NSColor.

Comment: is it not for swift 2 ?

Comment: A small addition: `func bold(_ text:String, _ size:CGFloat)`. I added size to the bold so I can control it from outside. Also, I missed the `AvenirNext-Medium` font in this function so took me few minutes to understand why I can't see my font. Heads up.

Answer (score 126):

```
var normalText = "Hi am normal"

var boldText  = "And I am BOLD!"

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:normalText)

var attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]
var boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: boldText, attributes:attrs)

attributedString.append(boldString)
```

When you want to assign it to a label:

```
yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: note: appendAttributedString has been renamed to .append()

Answer (score 31):

edit/update: **Xcode 13.1 • Swift 5.5.1**

If you know HTML and CSS you can use it to easily control the font style, color and size of your attributed string as follow:

> Discussion
> The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that is, the options dictionary includes documentType with a value of html). It will try to synchronize with the main thread, fail, and time out. Calling it from the main thread works (but can still time out if the HTML contains references to external resources, which should be avoided at all costs). The HTML import mechanism is meant for implementing something like markdown (that is, text styles, colors, and so on), not for general HTML import.

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var html2AttStr: NSAttributedString? {
        try? NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)

    }
}
```

---

```
"<style type=\"text/css\">#red{color:#F00}#green{color:#0F0}#blue{color: #00F; font-weight: Bold; font-size: 32}</style><span id=\"red\" >Red,</span><span id=\"green\" > Green </span><span id=\"blue\">and Blue</span>".html2AttStr
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this in Swift 2 Xcode, but the font is not being applied. Here is the String:  `<link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Frank+Ruhl+Libre\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> <span style=\"font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', sans-serif;\">שלום</span>`

Comment: If it style use WebKit to parse HTML strings in NSAttributedString, careful using it in a background thread...

Comment: What is the benefits of using this approach rather than @prajeet answer?

Comment: @EmreÖnder It is just personal preference. If you know html it will be easier to simply use the extension above.

Comment: bold doesnt work

Answer (score 30):

If you're working with localised strings, you might not be able to rely on the bold string always being at the end of the sentence. If this is the case then the following works well:

e.g. Query **"blah"** does not match any items

```
/* Create the search query part of the text, e.g. "blah". 
   The variable 'text' is just the value entered by  the user. */
let searchQuery = "\"\(text)\""

/* Put the search text into the message */
let message = "Query \(searchQuery). does not match any items"

/* Find the position of the search string. Cast to NSString as we want
   range to be of type NSRange, not Swift's Range<Index> */
let range = (message as NSString).rangeOfString(searchQuery)

/* Make the text at the given range bold. Rather than hard-coding a text size,
   Use the text size configured in Interface Builder. */
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(label.font.pointSize), range: range)

/* Put the text in a label */
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: After hours of searching, this is the only answer which found a solution to my problem. +1

Answer (score 11):

I extended David West's great answer so that you can input a string and tell it *all* the substrings you would like to embolden:

```
func addBoldText(fullString: NSString, boldPartsOfString: Array<NSString>, font: UIFont!, boldFont: UIFont!) -> NSAttributedString {
    let nonBoldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName:font!]
    let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName:boldFont!]
    let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString as String, attributes:nonBoldFontAttribute)
    for i in 0 ..< boldPartsOfString.count {
        boldString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: fullString.rangeOfString(boldPartsOfString[i] as String))
    }
    return boldString
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
let normalFont = UIFont(name: "Dosis-Medium", size: 18)
let boldSearchFont = UIFont(name: "Dosis-Bold", size: 18)
self.UILabel.attributedText = addBoldText("Check again in 30 days to find more friends", boldPartsOfString: ["Check", "30 days", "find", "friends"], font: normalFont!, boldFont: boldSearchFont!)
```

This will embolden all the substrings you want bolded in your given string

Comment: Is it possible to have same word bold in two different places? EX: "Check again in 30 days to find 30 friends". How do you make both "30" bold? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

### Swift 4 and higher

For Swift 4 and higher that is a good way:

```
    let attributsBold = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)]
    let attributsNormal = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)]
    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hi ", attributes:attributsNormal)
    let boldStringPart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "John", attributes:attributsBold)
    attributedString.append(boldStringPart)
  
    yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

In the Label the Text looks like: "Hi **John**"

Answer (score 10):

This is the best way that I have come up with. Add a function you can call from anywhere and add it to a file without a class like Constants.swift and then you can embolden words within any string, on numerous occasions by calling just **ONE LINE** of code:

To go in a constants.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

func addBoldText(fullString: NSString, boldPartOfString: NSString, font: UIFont!, boldFont: UIFont!) -> NSAttributedString {
   let nonBoldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName:font!]
   let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName:boldFont!]
   let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString as String, attributes:nonBoldFontAttribute)
   boldString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: fullString.rangeOfString(boldPartOfString as String))
   return boldString
}
```

Then you can just call this one line of code for any UILabel:

```
self.UILabel.attributedText = addBoldText("Check again in 30 DAYS to find more friends", boldPartOfString: "30 DAYS", font: normalFont!, boldFont: boldSearchFont!)


//Mark: Albeit that you've had to define these somewhere:

let normalFont = UIFont(name: "INSERT FONT NAME", size: 15)
let boldFont = UIFont(name: "INSERT BOLD FONT", size: 15)
```

Answer (score 10):

Building on Jeremy Bader and David West's excellent answers, a Swift 3 extension:

```
extension String {
    func withBoldText(boldPartsOfString: Array<NSString>, font: UIFont!, boldFont: UIFont!) -> NSAttributedString {
        let nonBoldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName:font!]
        let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName:boldFont!]
        let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self as String, attributes:nonBoldFontAttribute)
        for i in 0 ..< boldPartsOfString.count {
            boldString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: (self as NSString).range(of: boldPartsOfString[i] as String))
        }
        return boldString
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let label = UILabel()
let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Italic", size: 24)!
let boldFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-BoldItalic", size: 24)!
label.attributedText = "Make sure your face is\nbrightly and evenly lit".withBoldText(
    boldPartsOfString: ["brightly", "evenly"], font: font, boldFont: boldFont)
```

Answer (score 6):

usage....

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
            .appendWith(weight: .semibold, "almost bold")
            .appendWith(color: .white, weight: .bold, " white and bold")
            .appendWith(color: .black, ofSize: 18.0, " big black")
```

two cents...

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    @discardableResult func appendWith(color: UIColor = UIColor.darkText, weight: UIFont.Weight = .regular, ofSize: CGFloat = 12.0, _ text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString{
        let attrText = NSAttributedString.makeWith(color: color, weight: weight, ofSize:ofSize, text)
        self.append(attrText)
        return self
    }

}
extension NSAttributedString {

    public static func makeWith(color: UIColor = UIColor.darkText, weight: UIFont.Weight = .regular, ofSize: CGFloat = 12.0, _ text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: ofSize, weight: weight), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color]
        return NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes:attrs)
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS 11 or greater (due to the UIFont.Weight usage).

Answer (score 5):

Accepting as valid the response of [Prajeet Shrestha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425884/prajeet-shrestha) in this thread, I would like to extend his solution using the Label if it is known and the traits of the font.

**Swift 4**

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    @discardableResult func normal(_ text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let normal = NSAttributedString(string: text)
        append(normal)

        return self
    }

    @discardableResult func bold(_ text: String, withLabel label: UILabel) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        //generate the bold font
        var font: UIFont = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName , size: label.font.pointSize)!
        font = UIFont(descriptor: font.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold) ?? font.fontDescriptor, size: font.pointSize)

        //generate attributes
        let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]
        let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text, attributes: attrs)

        //append the attributed text
        append(boldString)

        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Super easy way to do this.

```
    let text = "This string is having multiple font"
    let attributedText = 
    NSMutableAttributedString.getAttributedString(fromString: text)

    attributedText.apply(font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24), subString: 
    "This")

    attributedText.apply(font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24), onRange: 
    NSMakeRange(5, 6))
```

For more detail click here:
https://github.com/iOSTechHub/AttributedString

Comment: How about semi bold?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @Houman use the library above and use the `apply` method with the font you want

Comment: Command .getAttributedString(fromString:) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

For -> Search **Television** by size

1-way using NString and its Range

```
let query = "Television"
let headerTitle = "size"
let message = "Search \(query) by \(headerTitle)"
let range = (message as NSString).range(of: query)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: label1.font.pointSize), range: range)
label1.attributedText = attributedString
```

another **without** using NString and its Range

```
let query = "Television"
let headerTitle = "size"
let (searchText, byText) = ("Search ", " by \(headerTitle)")
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: searchText)
let byTextAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: byText)
let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: label1.font.pointSize)]
let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: query, attributes:attrs)
attributedString.append(boldString)
attributedString.append(byTextAttributedString)
label1.attributedText = attributedString
```

swift5

Answer (score 2):

This could be useful

```
class func createAttributedStringFrom (string1 : String ,strin2 : String, attributes1 : Dictionary<String, NSObject>, attributes2 : Dictionary<String, NSObject>) -> NSAttributedString{

let fullStringNormal = (string1 + strin2) as NSString
let attributedFullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullStringNormal as String)

attributedFullString.addAttributes(attributes1, range: fullStringNormal.rangeOfString(string1))
attributedFullString.addAttributes(attributes2, range: fullStringNormal.rangeOfString(strin2))
return attributedFullString
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0

Convert html to string and font change as per your requirement.

```
do {

     let str = try NSAttributedString(data: ("I'm a normal text and <b>this is my bold part . </b>And I'm again in the normal text".data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!), options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

     myLabel.attributedText = str
     myLabel.font =  MONTSERRAT_BOLD(23)
     myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
} catch {
     print(error)
}
```

```
func MONTSERRAT_BOLD(_ size: CGFloat) -> UIFont
{
    return UIFont(name: "MONTSERRAT-BOLD", size: size)!
}
```

Comment: You should convert your string to data using utf8. Note that Data conforms to collection in Swift 3 so you can initialize Data with your string utf8 collection view `Data("I'm a normal text and <b>this is my bold part . </b>And I'm again in the normal text".utf8)` and set the character encoding in options `[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.1**
use `NSAttributedString.Key` instead of `NSAttributedStringKey`

```
let test1Attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font : UIFont(name: "CircularStd-Book", size: 14)!]
let test2Attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font : UIFont(name: "CircularStd-Bold", size: 16)!]

let test1 = NSAttributedString(string: "\(greeting!) ", attributes:test1Attributes)
let test2 = NSAttributedString(string: firstName!, attributes:test2Attributes)
let text = NSMutableAttributedString()

text.append(test1)
text.append(test2)
return text
```

Answer (score 1):

for making mixed-type strings (Attributed String ) It is better to use Xcode's interface builder if the text is static.
it is very easy and convenient.[image]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Just use code something like this:

```
 let font = UIFont(name: "Your-Font-Name", size: 10.0)!

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: noteLabel.attributedText!)
        let boldedRange = NSRange(attributedText.string.range(of: "Note:")!, in: attributedText.string)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : font], range: boldedRange)
        noteLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 0):

two liner in swift 4:

```
            button.setAttributedTitle(.init(string: "My text", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)]), for: .selected)
            button.setAttributedTitle(.init(string: "My text", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular)]), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions (iOS 15+) you can use [`AttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring/3796160-init) to create Markdown strings  :

```swift
let rawMarkdown = "This is **bold**"
let content;

do {
    content = try AttributedString(markdown: rawMarkdown)
} catch {
    content = AttributedString(rawMarkdown)
}
```

and display them with Swift UI's `Text`:

```swift
Text(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 15+ and if you want to change font also.

```
    do {
        let text = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<b>", with: "**").replacingOccurrences(of: "</b>", with: "**")
        let options = AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace)
        var attributedString = try AttributedString(markdown: text, options: options)
        attributedString.font = font
        return attributedString
    } catch {
        return AttributedString(stringLiteral: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing multiple occurrence of words to be bold in string you can use this function directly or in String extension.

```
 func addBoldText(text: String, substringsToBold: Array<String>, regularFont: UIFont, boldFont: UIFont) -> NSAttributedString {
    
    // Create an attributed string
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    // Apply regular font to the entire string
    attributedString.addAttributes([.font: regularFont], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))

    // Apply bold font to specific substrings
    for substringToBold in substringsToBold {
        var searchRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count)
        while let range = text.range(of: substringToBold, options: .caseInsensitive, range: Range(searchRange, in: text)) {
            attributedString.addAttributes([.font: boldFont], range: NSRange(range, in: text))
            searchRange.location = range.upperBound.utf16Offset(in: text)
            searchRange.length = text.utf16.count - searchRange.location
        }
    }
    return attributedString
}}
```

And how you will be gonna use this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Create a string
    let text = "Hello, World! This is the world we live in. Welcome to the world."

    // Define font attributes for regular and bold text
    let regularFont = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    let boldFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    
    // Define an array of substrings to make bold
    let substringsToBold = ["Hello", "world", "Welcome"]

    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributedText = addBoldText(text: text, substringsToBold: substringsToBold, regularFont: regularFont, boldFont: boldFont)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Please check a scrrenshot[image]

Answer (score -1):

Improving upon Prajeet Shrestha answer : -

You can make a generic extension for NSMutableAttributedString which involves less code. In this case I have chosen to use system font but you could adapt it so you can input the font name as a parameter.

```
    extension NSMutableAttributedString {

        func systemFontWith(text: String, size: CGFloat, weight: CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
            let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size, weight: weight)]
            let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
            self.append(string)
            return self
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using simple custom method written below.
You have give whole string in first parameter and text to be bold in the second parameter. Hope this will help.

```
func getAttributedBoldString(str : String, boldTxt : String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: str)
        let boldedRange = NSRange(str.range(of: boldTxt)!, in: str)
        attrStr.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold)], range: boldedRange)
        return attrStr
    }
```

**usage:**
initalString = I am a Boy

label.attributedText = getAttributedBoldString(str : initalString, boldTxt : "Boy")

resultant string = I am a **Boy**

Answer (score -1):

**Swift Attributed String**

The key point is to use `NSMutableAttributedString` to add attributes

set attributes to UILabel

```
let uiLabel = UILabel()
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World!")
uiLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

modify UILabel with attributes

```
let labelAttributedText = uiLabel.attributedText!
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelAttributedText)
let range = mutableAttributedString.mutableString.range(of: "World")
mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 21), range: range)
uiLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**For Swift 5 Xcode 15.0**

you can use the following sample code:

```swift
let message = "This message should be regular.\n And this message must be Bold.\n\nAnd this one should be regular again"
let boldMessage = "And this message must be Bold."
let boldRenge = (message as NSString).range(of: boldMessage)
var attributedMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)])
attributedMessage.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold), range: boldRenge)
bodyParagraphLabel.attributedText = attributedMessage
```