# UIWebView inject CSS with loadHTMLString

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, uiwebview

I'm generating an HTML dynamically in my AppLogic:

```
let html = "<html><head></head><body><h1>hello world</h1></body></html>"
```

This is working fine together with my UIWebView:

```
webView?.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Is it also possible to pass a String which contains a CSS to the WebView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28532609/2303865