# Replace attributed string into NSMutableAttributedString In Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, string, swift3, nsattributedstring

I want to output like

> My name is **Pramod** Tapaniya

from below json.

```
{
    "text": "My name is B0$ Tapaniya.",
    "formats": {
            "formatId": [
                "B0$"
            ],
            "formatValue": [
                "Pramod"
            ]
    }
}
```

I have tried below code, but getting compile time error because I replacing String with Attributed String. I have used SwiftyJson for handle json.

```
let boldAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)]
let simpleAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)]

let strComm = NSMutableAttributedString(string: dict["text"].stringValue, attributes: simpleAttributes)
let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString()

attributedStr.append(strComm)

let arrFormatId = dict["formats"]["formatId"]
let arrFormatValue = dict["formats"]["formatValue"]

for var i in 0..<arrFormatId.count{
    let strBold = NSMutableAttributedString(string: arrFormatValue[i].stringValue, attributes: boldAttributes)
    attributedStr.mutableString.replaceOccurrences(of: arrFormatId[i].stringValue, with: strBold, options: .caseInsensitive, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedStr.length)) //Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableAttributedString' to expected argument type 'String'
}
return attributedStr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with this code

```
let boldAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)]
let simpleAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)]

let strComm = NSMutableAttributedString(string: dict["text"].stringValue, attributes: simpleAttributes)
let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString()

attributedStr.append(strComm)

let arrFormatId = dict["formats"]["formatId"]
let arrFormatValue = dict["formats"]["formatValue"]

for var i in 0..<arrFormatId.count{
    let strBold = NSMutableAttributedString(string: arrFormatValue[i].stringValue, attributes: boldAttributes)
    while attributedStr.mutableString.contains(arrFormatId[i].stringValue) {
        let range = attributedStr.mutableString.range(of: arrFormatId[i].stringValue)
        attributedStr.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: strBold)
    }
}
return attributedStr
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be

```
var text = "My name is B0$ Tapaniya"
var arrayID = ["B0$"]

var arrayValue =  ["Pramod"]

if arrayID.count == arrayValue.count {
    for key in arrayID {
        text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with:arrayValue[arrayID.index(of: key)!])
    }

 // Now use below methods

    let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    formattedString
   .normal(text)
   .bold(arrayValue.joined(separator: ","))   

}
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/37992022/4601900

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    @discardableResult func bold(_ text:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)]

        let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(text)", attributes:attrs)
        self.append(boldString)
        return self
    }

    @discardableResult func normal(_ text:String)->NSMutableAttributedString {
        let normal =  NSAttributedString(string: text)
        self.append(normal)
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
var testDict = ["text": "My name is B0$ Tapaniya.","formats": ["formatId": ["B0$"],"formatValue": ["Pramod"]]] as [String : AnyObject]
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: testDict["text"] as! String)
var formatIDS = testDict["formats"]?.value(forKey: "formatId") as! [String]
var formatValues = testDict["formats"]?.value(forKey: "formatValue") as! [String]

for i in 0..<formatIDS.count {
    attrString.mutableString.replaceOccurrences(of: formatIDS[i], with: formatValues[i], options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))
    attrString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12.0)], range: attrString.mutableString.range(of: formatValues[i] as String))
}
print(attrString)
```

Comment: "Pramod" as bold. You just replace the string.

Comment: Updated the answer.