# Difference in how a UILabel is shown in the interface builder and in the simulator

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have created a .xib file and have added a `UILabel` with attributed text. The contents of the label consists of 2 words - one is in regular font while the other word is bold. 
The interface builder shows the label correctly as follows

[image: interface builder]

However, when the app is run on the simulator, the following is shown-
[image: simulator]

Can anyone point out why this is happening?

Comment: string and arrtributed string created via inspector is not supported in IOS devices, if you need the Same OP you need to create as progrmatically : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496093/making-text-bold-using-attributed-string-in-swift

Comment: It seems to work fine for Xcode 10.1. Please share xcode version and code.

Comment: As far as i think you are updating the value programatically.

Comment: @KhushalDugar Xcode version is Version 10.1 (10B61). I have not created an outlet for that UILabel, so I don't think I am changing the value programatically.

Comment: Have you by any chance changed the `UILabel` text programatically using `myLabel.text = "Update Item"` ?

Comment: @MarwenDoukh No, I have not created an outlet for that label

Comment: Can you try this with a built in system font? If that works it might indicate that something is wrong with the custom `PT Sans` font.

Comment: @wvteijlingen You are right. If `Arial` font is used, this issue is resolved.

Comment: @iaaflaafc: I have added an answer regarding custom fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as it works with a system font such as Arial, it is probably a problem with the custom font not being recognised. Try the following:

1. Did you add the custom fonts files to your Xcode project, and to the build target?
2. Did you add them to the `Info.plist` using the `UIAppFonts` key? This key should contain an array of the names of the font files you added to your project (e.g. `Custom-Font.ttf`)

Answer (score -2):

Please try

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

this might be the issue.